# Imagick giving me Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image

Tags: php, imagick

I'm pretty sure I've installed my imagick correctly.
[image]

When I try and run something as simple as displaying an image with no changes to it like so:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$image = new Imagick('image.jpg');

echo $image;
```

It displays a broken image.

When I attempt to display it without the header it gives me an error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'unable to open image `image.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2642' in [my-php-file-uri]:4 Stack trace: #0 [my-php-file-uri](4): Imagick->__construct('image.jpg') #1 {main} thrown in [my-php-file-uri] on line 4
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason was because I had to include the full file-path URI